# Sum of power series $\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, problem-solving

Consider the power series defined by $\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$: $\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+...$.  Its radius of convergence is clearly 1, for any $x \geq 1$ diverges by comparison with the harmonic series, and any $0 \leq x < 1$ converges by comparison with a geometric series.

Is there a way to calculate its sum? What method can be used?  **I request that answers describe the appropriate method but do not complete the solution.**

Comment: You could start with the series for the sum of powers of $x^2$ and then integrate term by term on one side.

Comment: arctanh${}{}{}$

Comment: It may be slightly easier to see where it comes from if you reindex the series starting from $n = 0$ rather than $n = 1.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $f(x) = x+\frac {x^2}2 +\frac {x^3}3 +\frac {x^4}4 +\frac {x^5}5 +\frac {x^6}6 +\cdots$ then consider

- $\frac12 f(x^2)$
- $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$

and see whether this suggests anything familiar

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$  Then $f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n-2}=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty (x^2)^m$.
Sum the geometric series and integrate to get $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=\arctan x.$$
Now use the identity $\arctan (ix)\equiv i\operatorname{artanh}x$.